# EC2: "Connection refused" to all instances after changing ownership of /var

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently changed the ownership of the **/var** directory in my EC2 instance from "root" to "ec2-user", and once I did that, I was unable to SSH back into the server (even though port 22 is open in the security group). Now when I try to connect through that instance or any new instance, I get this message:

```
Error connecting to ________, reason:
-> Connection refused
```

When I check the system logs, I see this:

> Starting sshd: /var/empty/sshd must be owned by root and not group or
>   world-writable.
>
> [FAILED]

Any ideas on how I can get back into the server? I tried creating a new instance and mounting the older volume there, but I can't even SSH into the new instance, as I get that same "Connection refused" message.

Comment: Not sure why this question was voted down. Seems a reasonable explanation of a problem. I have run into similar problems myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to create a new instance with a new ebs disk and fresh OS. Then boot it and attach the broken OS disk -  you should then be able to modify your files and fix your problem.

Comment: I mentioned in the OP that I get the same "Connection refused" message when I try and boot into a new instance.

Comment: I appreciate that - this is why I suggested to first boot a fresh instance and then after boot attach the broken disk and mount it. Sometimes I find that if you attach both disks before boot it attaches the wrong one to the root volume.

Comment: Will is right. Don't try to attach the broken volume when you create the instance, do it afterward. Maybe this can also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564228/ec2-ssh-login-failed-permission-denied-publickey/18565744#18565744

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happens to us after reboots. It happens apparently just because (no changes, no editing of permissions or anything). It is incredibly annoying.

To fix it you need to

-stop the instance (you will lose the IP, unless you have and elastic IP associated)

-detach the root volume

-grab another instance in the same availability zone

-attach the volume to the new instance

-boot the new instance

-log on to the new instance and mount the volume you detached from the broken instance

-go to /var/empty and fix sshd ownership and permissions (must be drwx--x--x root:root)

-logout from the new instance

-stop it

-detach the fixed volume

-re attach it to the broken instance (make sure you attach as root volume, probably using /dev/sda1)

-re start the silly thing

-pray

If you are lucky you will now be able to ssh again.

This has been happening to us for about a year. We've already made the decision to move our instances to Digital Ocean, but it may help any other poor souls out there.